# Which is the python function that is equivalent to the Arduino byte() function?

Tags: python, arduino, byte, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to control a Roomba (iRobot Create 2) which has a open interface command. I'm able to control it with Arduino with the following lines:

```
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.write(byte(128)); // Starts communication
delay(50);
Serial.write(byte(132)); // Enter full access to roomba mode
Serial.write(byte(137)); // Command for driving
Serial.write(byte(0x00));  // The rest is the driving configuration for Spin counter clockwise
Serial.write(byte(0xc8));
Serial.write(byte(0x00));
Serial.write(byte(0x01));
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same with Raspberry Pi 3b+, but I can't find the equivalent function for Python. Can I get some help?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Presumably you can see that your code is unreadable. Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3890632) and [edit] your question.

Comment: `byte` here is not a function, it's a type. Python doesn't have the concept of a single byte. Instead of blindly trying to translate the code, rewrite it to do what it actually does i.e. sends 7 bytes.

Comment: Yes, byte is a type, sorry for that mistake. But I finally know how to do the same conversion in python: bytes(chr(128).encode('utf-8'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in trying to translate individual bits of a language to another, as there might not be an equivalent thing or there would be a better way.

In this case the whole thing in Python would be:

```py
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 115200)
ser.write(bytes([128]))
time.sleep(0.05)
ser.write(bytes([132,137,0x00,0xc8,0x00,0x01]))
```